# Parsing XML from RSS Feed in Cloud Code

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to shift my XML parsing from local XMLPullParser to a server and have started learning Parse.com cloud code for this. I want to parse RSS Feeds to get titles and links of articles. I searched and found that I need to use sax.js and xmlreadear.js to do this. 
SOURCE: https://parse.com/questions/how-to-get-xml-from-a-seperate-server-in-cloud-code

I have downloaded it and also read some other GitHub repos using it but unfortunately couldnt really understand. I have a very basic knowledge of JavaScript which I gained via Codecademy.

Can anybody tell me a little bit how to move forward? I have spent more than a day figuring it out, maybe lack of JS knowledge is coming in the way

Comment: Is there any processing besides parsing? If you parse rss feed in the cloud, create parse object and download parse object on android it won't make sense to me.

Comment: The thing I am planning to do is to reduce the load on the mobile device. I want to do two type of parsing. First I would take the links of feeds from the RSS links, and then use the links to parse the articles and get title, body and images (if any). I may be wrong here but I think it is called using XPath in the article. I would then download only these 3 things to mobile device and display it.

Comment: You may get better responses by asking specific questions about what you're having trouble with.  This question is almost impossible to answer.